# calling function from its body

Tags: python, function, recursion

When discovering solutions for the permutations of the list I have stumbled upon this hardcoded [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7733966). I will list the code here:

```
def permutations(head, tail=''):
    if len(head) == 0: print tail
    else:
        for i in range(len(head)):
            permutations(head[0:i] + head[i+1:], tail+head[i])

permutations('abc')
```

Now, I totally do not understand, what happens when we call function from its body. Could you please explain to me, why it works, why it is needed here, and where I can read about this in more detail.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a recursive call: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/

Comment: I would step through the function by hand for a small list (e.g. 3-4 values). The computer term to search for is recursion

Comment: Try posting a letter through your front door with an instruction inside it to post it through your front door, it'll achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive call. Basically recursion is based off of a base case, which if fulfilled, will stop. Otherwise the function will call itself.

You can read more here:

https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

It's also worth noting, that while recursion can make code more readable, in Python recursion should be used with caution, as the default recursion limit is relatively conservative.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link! It is an easygoing one!